# Spring MVC remote Thymeleaf UrlTemplateResolver fragment issues

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a test running where I have setup two Spring Boot applications one with a header fragment and the other with an index page.

Fragment application = `localhost:8080`

```
<header th:fragment="application-header" id="application-header">
CONTENT 
</header>
```

Index application = `localhost:7950`

```
<header th:include="http://localhost:8080/application-header.tpl.html ::
   [//header[@id='application-header']]">
</header>
```

The header displays properly within the calling application.

I have a few problems with the way things are acting right now.

1:  If I update the Fragment application the update will not propagate to the Index application unless I restart the application.

2: If the Fragment application is unavailable on the first index load the Index application will fail with a 500 error.

3: I had to use `[//header[@id='application-header']]` the fragment name did not work within the Index application.  Not really a problem but I thought from reading that the fragment name would have worked

```
@Bean
public UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver(){
    UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver = new UrlTemplateResolver();
    urlTemplateResolver.setOrder(20);
    return urlTemplateResolver;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your config - overriding autoconfig in order to add in UrlTemplateResolver to SpringBoot - for Thymeleaf 2 or 3.

Comment: The app uses Spring Boot. Config is automatic. V2

Comment: hmmm - when I try using th:include="http://anything .... " it attempts to resolve it from ... "template/http://www.anything.com " -- meaning, it does not find it and provides an error message. So I believe that I do not have UrlTemplateResolver configured. Oh! - are you saying this will work automatically in V2? I will try that. - Thanks!

Comment: @Gary actually I need to take a look. It will be tomorrow. Seems i might of had to add something to config.

Comment: @Gary I found it. Added to the question

Answer (score 0):

To include a fragment you should use the structure of web directories of the application.

```
<header th:include="/application-header.tpl.html :: header[@id='application-header']]">
</header>
```

Comment: This is for url based templates not local

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of always getting cached responses from UrlTemplateResolver by modify the cachable property with the thymeleaf cache setting:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringTemplateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver springResourceTemplateResolver;

    @Value("${spring.thymeleaf.cache}")
    Boolean springThymeleafCache;

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

        UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver = new UrlTemplateResolver();
        urlTemplateResolver.setCacheable(springThymeleafCache); // explicit set cacheable, otherwise it will be always cached

        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(urlTemplateResolver);
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(springResourceTemplateResolver);

        return templateEngine;
    }
}
```

My application.yml contains the following:

```
spring:
  profiles: local
thymeleaf:
  cache: false // spring boot default is true
  prefix: file:src/main/resources/templates/
```